# Jquery Animation Lag

Tags: jquery, lag

I've got my site working, well there's many bugs to be ironed out, although when I built the site locally, And used the "category" buttons to filter the gallery, it didn't lag at all, If you switch back and forth with the filter buttons, you'll see what I'm talking about. I don't know how to resurrect this :(

I'm using the quicksand.js plugin and this is what actually defines my gallery, I've included comments so you don't have to read too much! :( :(

http://shannonhochkins.v5.cloudsvr.com.au/

```
//Gallery

$(document).ready(function(){
    var limit = 28
    var items = $('#stage li'),
        itemsByTags = {};


        // Looping though all the li items:

        $('#stage li').each(function(i){

            var elem = $(this),
                tags = elem.data('tags').split(',');

            // Adding a data-id attribute. Required by the Quicksand plugin:
            elem.attr('data-id',i);

            $.each(tags,function(key,value){

                // Removing extra whitespace:
                value = $.trim(value);

                if(!(value in itemsByTags)){
                    // Create an empty array to hold this item:
                    itemsByTags[value] = [];
                }

                // Each item is added to one array per tag:
                itemsByTags[value].push(elem);
            });
        });

        // Creating the "Everything" option in the menu:
        createList('Everything',items);

        // Looping though the arrays in itemsByTags:
        $.each(itemsByTags,function(k,v){
            createList(k,v);
        });

        $('#galleryNav a').live('click',function(e){

            var link = $(this);
            link.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            // Using the Quicksand plugin to animate the li items.
            // It uses data('list') defined by our createList function:
            $('#stage').quicksand(link.data('list').find('li').slice(0, limit).show().animate({opacity:1.0}, 300));

            e.preventDefault();         
        });

        $('#galleryNav a:first').click();


        var high_performance = true;  
        var $performance_container = $('#performance-toggle');
        var $original_html = $performance_container.html();

        $performance_container.find('a').live('click', function(e) {
          if (high_performance) {
            $preferences.useScaling = false;
            $performance_container.html('CSS3 scaling turned off. Try the demo again. <a href="#toggle">Reverse</a>.');
            high_performance = false;
          } else {
            $preferences.useScaling = true;
            $performance_container.html($original_html);
            high_performance = true;
          }
          e.preventDefault();
        });

        function createList(text,items){

            // This is a helper function that takes the
            // text of a menu button and array of li items

            // Creating an empty unordered list:
            var ul = $('<ul>',{'class':'hidden'});

            $.each(items,function(){
                // Creating a copy of each li item
                // and adding it to the list:

                $(this).clone().appendTo(ul);
            });

            ul.appendTo('#container');

            // Creating a menu item. The unordered list is added
            // as a data parameter (available via .data('list'):

            var a = $('<a>',{           
                href:'#',
                id: text +'li',
                data: {list:ul}
            }).appendTo('#galleryNav');
        }

        $("#galleryNav #Animationli").append("<span class='Animation'></span>");
        $("#galleryNav #Modellingli").append("<span class='Modelling'></span>");
        $("#galleryNav #Environmentli").append("<span class='Environments'></span>");
        $("#galleryNav #Riggingli").append("<span class='Rigging'></span>");
        $("#galleryNav #Pluginsli").append("<span class='Plugins'></span>");
        $("#galleryNav #Websitesli").append("<span class='Websites'></span>");

        $("#galleryNav a").live('mouseenter',function() {
            $(this).find('span').stop(true).animate({opacity: 1.0, marginTop: -50}, 400);
        });
        $("#galleryNav a").live('mouseleave',function() {                       
            $(this).find('span').animate({opacity: 0.5, marginTop: 0}, 400);
        });
        $(".stage li img").live('mouseenter',function() {
            $(this).stop(true);
            $(this).animate({width: "80%",opacity: 0.45}, 500);

        });
        $(".stage li img").live('mouseleave',function() {
            $(this).animate({width: "94%", opacity: 1.00}, 500);
        }); 
        $('#Animationli,#Riggingli,#Environmentli,#Modellingli,#Pluginsli,#Websitesli').live('click', function(event){

            var x = event.pageX,
                y = event.pageY;

            $('#cloudNavGallery').stop(true).animate({
                top:y,
                left:x
            },600);
        });

    initRoulette();
});
```

Comment: I have no Animation lag here (Btw nice rocket ship *hint hint*). I would like to note that the images you server on your page have a `no-cache` against them. I'm on 768K DSL and it takes me about 3-5 minutes to fully load your page. It would be nice if you allowed for some caching. :)

Comment: I'm on 15mbit, and it's even slow here! You have a lot of images, and a lot of large images, you need to try and minimize them with something like RIOT, pngcrush etc. and turn on the cache on the server so the images is'nt loaded every time. Use sprites for the thumbnails and other techniques to speed up load times, Yahoo had an old article with some great tips somewhere, but there are plenty of info online on optimizing page speed.

Comment: Hi Guys, I know there's a lot to iron out on the page, many many hours spent on this to get it to it's point, I've not yet refined it!  Although, this "no-cache" thing you're talking about, what exactly do I say to my hoster to get them to enable it?